# Автоинкремент поля при обновлении записи

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно в SQLAlchemy сделать автоинкремент поля version при UPDATE из приведенной ниже модели

```
class Task(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'task'
    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    ...
    version = db.Column(db.BigInteger)
```

Я использую MySQL. так что db.Sequence не подходит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, можно реализовать через [эвенты](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html):

```
class Task(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'task'

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    version = db.Column(db.BigInteger)


@db.event.listens_for(Task.name, 'set')
def receive_set(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    if value != oldvalue:
        # print(f'Сработал EVENT set. {target}, value={value}, oldvalue={oldvalue}')
        if target.version is not None:
            target.version += 1
        else:
            target.version = 1
```

Допустим, мы создали объект с первоночальной `version` = 1:

```
t = Task(id=1, name='Vasya', version=1)

db.session.add(t)
db.session.commit()
```

Запросим версию "записи":

```
t = Task.query.get(1)

print(t.version)
```

Получим `1`. Затем, изменим значение поле `name` на другое значение в этой же сессии и снова посмотрим на `version`:

```
t.name = 'Vasya2'

print(t.version)
```

Сейчас `version` равна `2`. И так далее...

Также, "update" отслеживание полей и изменение `version` можно делать более "хардкорно", в этом случае пример также работает как и выше, но какие это могут быть подводные камни с SQLAlchemy я не могу сказать, но это работает через магический метод `__setattr__`:

```
class Task(db.Model):

    __tablename__ = 'task'

    id = db.Column(db.BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(255))
    version = db.Column(db.BigInteger)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        # "Аналог" события SQLAlchemy на атрибут объекта
        if name == 'name':
            if self.version is not None:
                new_version = self.version + 1
            else:
                new_version = 1

            super().__setattr__('version', new_version)

        super().__setattr__(name, value)
```